Asymptotic expansion of an integral by expanding series first
Question: as $s\to\infty$ use the substitution $u = {\rm e}^{-x}\,$ to obtain the first 2 terms in asymptotic expansion in the integral:
$$
\operatorname{B}\left(s,t\right) =
\int_{0}^{1}u^{s - 1}\,\,\left(\,{1 - u}\,\right)^{t-1}\,{\rm du}
$$
where $s$, $t$ are positive. what happens as
$t \to \infty $?
What I've done: I used the hint and get the integral:
$$
\operatorname{B }=  \int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-xs}\,
\left(\,{1 - {\rm e}^{-x}}\,\right)^{t-1}
\,\,{\rm d}x
$$
Now to get the asymptotic expansion, I wanted to use ${\it Watson's\ lemma}$, for which I would need the asymptotic expansion of
$\left(\,{1 - {\rm e}^{-x}}\,\right)^{t-1}$ as
$x \to 0^{+}$, but I got stuck on this because
$x = 0$ is a singular point.
I've tried to expand the bracket first and then expand the exponential, which gave
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\quad\mbox{with}
\quad a_0 = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\left(-1\right)^{n}\,\,{\left(t - 1\right)\ldots\left(t - n\right)\, \over n!}
$$
but this number blows up.
My question:

Shall I continue trying to get an expansion like this, or shall I transform the integral further so that it is in an appropriate form $?$.
In either case, how shall I continue $?$.

Any hints or full solutions are welcome !.

Assume that $\operatorname{Re}(t)>0$ and $t$ is fixed. You can expand
\begin{align*}
(1 - {\rm e}^{ - x} )^{t - 1} & = x^{t - 1} \left( {\frac{{1 - {\rm e}^{ - x} }}{x}} \right)^{t - 1}  = x^{t - 1} \left( {\frac{{ - x}}{{{\rm e}^{ - x}  - 1}}} \right)^{1 - t} \\ & = x^{t - 1} \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{B_n^{(1 - t)} }}{{n!}}x^n }  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{{B_n^{(1 - t)} }}{{n!}}x^{t + n - 1} } ,
\end{align*}
as $x\to 0^+$, where the $B^{(\ell)}_n$ are the Bernoulli numbers of order $\ell$ (see, e.g., $\S24.16$(i)). Then, by Watson's lemma,
$$
B(s,t) \sim \frac{{\Gamma (t)}}{{s^t }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \binom{n + t - 1}{n}\frac{{B_n^{(1 - t)} }}{{s^n }}}  = \frac{{\Gamma (t)}}{{s^t }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\binom{-t}{n}\frac{{B_n^{(1 - t)} }}{{s^n }}} 
$$
as $s\to+\infty$. (In fact, this asymptotic expansion is valid in the sector $|\arg s|\le \pi-\delta<\pi$.) To obtain an asymptotics for large $t$ and fixed $s$, note that $B(s,t)=B(t,s)$.
